# Prove that if $f$ is smooth on a compact set then $f'(x+h) - f'(x)$ approaches zero as $h$ approaches zero uniformly in $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, compactness

> Prove that if $f$ is infinitely differentiable on a compact set then $f'(x+h) - f'(x)$ approaches zero as $h$ approaches zero uniformly in $x$

I know that any function that is continuous on a compact set is uniformly continuous. I realize that this may be a basic question but I do not know how that fact translates into this question. By mean value theorem, there exists $0 < h_1 < h$ such that $f'(x+h) - f'(x) = f''(x+h_1)h$, but I am not sure what to do. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: If $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$, I’m not sure how $f’(x+h)$  is defined on that interval. Perhaps it’s better to require $f$ to be a compactly supported function defined on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

After taking into account Ted Shifrin's comment, here's a general fact:

> Let $V$ be any normed vector space. If $\phi:\Bbb{R}^n\to V$ is continuous and compactly supported, then $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}^n}\|\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)\|=0$, i.e $\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)$ approaches $0$, uniformly with respect to $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$, as $h\to 0$.

If you want, you can take $V=\Bbb{R}$ and $n=1$, so that you're dealing with continuous compactly supported functions $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$.

To prove the theorem, note that continuous compactly supported functions on $\Bbb{R}^n$ are uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (why?). Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be given. By uniform continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all pairs of points $p,q\in\Bbb{R}^n$, if $\|p-q\|\leq \delta$, then $\|\phi(p)-\phi(q)\|\leq\epsilon$.

Ok, so for such a $\delta>0$, consider any point $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$, and any $h\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\|h\|\leq \delta$. Then, the points $x$ and $x+h$ are at most $\delta$ apart, and hence $\|\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)\|\leq \epsilon$. Since $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$ was arbitrary (and here's the important thing: uniform continuity means the $\delta$ doesn't depend on the choice of $x$), we can take the supremum:
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in\Bbb{R}^n}\|\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)\|\leq \epsilon.
\end{align}
i.e we showed, using uniform continuity of $\phi$, that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $h\in\Bbb{R}^n$, if $\|h\|\leq \delta$, then $\sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}^n}\|\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)\|\leq \epsilon$. This literally means $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}^n}|\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)|=0$.

---

Now, you just apply this to $\phi=f'$ when $V=\Bbb{R}$ and $n=1$.

The above is a general fact. If you want to specialize to compactly supported infinitely differentiable functions, then the mean-value theorem (which you didn't quite state properly) actually gives you a slightly stronger result, namely a uniform Lipschitz control. We have for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and $h\in\Bbb{R}$, there is some point $c$ in the interval between $x$ and $x+h$ such that
\begin{align}
f'(x+h)-f'(x)=f''(c)\cdot h.
\end{align}
So, taking absolute values, and using the trivial bound $|f''(c)|\leq \|f''\|_{\infty}$, we get
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in\Bbb{R}}|f'(x+h)-f'(x)|\leq \|f''\|_{\infty}\cdot |h|.
\end{align}
This is a uniform Lipschitz condition, which implies uniform convergence of the translates, because as $h\to 0$, the RHS vanishes (so this is just a simple squeeze theorem application).